# Android. Start fragment from adb

Tags: android, android-fragments, adb

I want to run a fragment via adb shell. Do so

```
adb shell am start -n com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity -e":android:show_fragment" com.example.myapplication.BlankFragment2
```

result

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.example.myapplication/.MainActivity (has extras) }
```

but only the activity opens without the fragment. What i do wrong?

Comment: Do you have code in `MainActivity` to handle that extra?

Comment: No. How can i do this?

Comment: In `onCreate()`, call `getIntent()` to get the `Intent` used to create the activity. Call `getStringExtra()` to retrieve the value for your extra. Use the value to decide what `FragmentTransaction` to create and `commit()` to display a fragment. Note that passing a fully-qualified class name as an `Intent` extra is a poor choice from a security standpoint, particularly if you intend to just blindly show that fragment. There were security bugs years ago in Android related to this, that have since been fixed.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But this is the only way to open the fragment? can i do this as with activity without writing code, using only adb?

Comment: "can i do this as with activity without writing code, using only adb?" -- I certainly hope not. If you can, the developers of the app have a security flaw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't open Fragment without coding just using adb. ADB works with system. Activity is a part of system, but not Fragment.

To open Fragment from ADB in your Activity in onCreate method you need to check Extra:

```
    val showFragment = intent.getStringExtra("show_fragment")
    if (showFragment != null) {
        if (showFragment == "StreamListFragment") {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, StreamListFragment())
                .commit()
        }
    }
```

R.id.container - view container, where your fragment will settle.

And after that you can to use adb.

```
adb shell am start -n com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity --es "show_fragment" "StreamListFragment"
```